# python process stdout to a file not working

Tags: python, multithreading, stdout

Consider the code

### Update

```
def proc1():
    #do something
def proc2():
    #do something else

f1 = open("log1","w")
f2 = open("log2","w")

sys.stdout = f1
p1 = threading.Thread(target = proc1)
p1.start()
sys.stdout = f2
p2 = threading.Thread(target = proc2)
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

When i ran this, nothing is being logged, what is the problem, any basic error??

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that python is sharing the modules between threads.  So the `sys` module is the *same* sys module in `p1` and `p2`.  When you set `sys.stdout` to `f2`, both threads are then writing to that instead of to their own ones.  I would imagine that everything is getting written to `log2`, except anything which happens in `proc1` after you start is and before python has managed to set `sys.stdout` to `f2`.

What would be a more ... normal way to do this, without making things much more complex, is by passing the file handle to the thread:

```
def proc1(logfile=sys.stdout):
    # do stuff
    logfile.write("use this, f.write, rather than print...")
    # do more stuff...

f1 = open("test", "a")
p1 = threading.Thread(target=proc1, args=(f1,))
p1.start()

# ...
```

Which should work fine.

One thing I would also advise is putting all of your initialisation stuff (opening the file handle, starting the threads, etc) into a function.  Call it `main` or something.  Then you can start this function by putting this at the end of the file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This way, it's much much easier to switch over to the http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html library if you want to (if the things you're trying to do are blocking each other in python's GIL, and you actually need separate processes, not just threads).

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a suggestion. If you want to keep save your `sys.stdout`, save it before: `save_stdout = sys.stdout`

After change the sys.stdout, you can undo the changes with `sys.stdout = save_stdout`. Now, let's go with the code. While txt file is open you can't see any result. Therefore, close the file and voilà:

```
def proc1():
    #do something
def proc2():
    #do something else

save_stdout = sys.stdout
f1 = open("log1","w")
f2 = open("log2","w")

sys.stdout = f1
p1 = threading.Thread(target = proc1)
p1.start()
sys.stdout = f2
p2 = threading.Thread(target = proc2)
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
f1.close()
f2.close()
sys.stdout = save_stdout
```

You can close the files in the main script or inside the functions proc1 and proc2, whatever you want.